Bigquery one json data into bigquery table with elegant SQL
I have a bigquery table containing the below data(one column and one row)



Josn




{'A':{'min':0, 'max':10},'B':{'min':1, 'max':15},'C':{'min':10, 'max':18}}



I want to convert the json data into a table as shown below



Name
min_value
max_value




A
0
10


B
1
15


C
10
18



Currently, I only know the below method, does anyone have the elegant SQL to do the same thing?
SELECT 'A' AS name, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.A.min") as min_value, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.A.max") as max_value
FROM table_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B' AS name, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.B.min") as min_value, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.B.max") as max_value
FROM table_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C' AS name, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.C.min") as min_value, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(Json, "$.C.max") as max_value
FROM table_name


Check out the answer I gave on this question, that follows the same logic of dynamic pattern matching in a json to make a resulting table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78888825/how-to-retrieve-a-fixed-length-string-from-json-array/78898606#78898606

Consider below approach
select regexp_extract(row_data, r"^'(.+?)'") as name,
  regexp_extract(row_data, r"'min':(\d+)") min_value,
  regexp_extract(row_data, r"'max':(\d+)") max_value
from your_table,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_col, r"'.+?':{.+?}")) as row_data    

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

Another variation of above is
select regexp_extract(row_data, r"^'(.+?)'") as name,
  json_value(min_max, '$.min') as min_value,
  json_value(min_max, '$.max') as max_value
from your_table,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_col, r"'.+?':{.+?}")) as row_data,
unnest([regexp_extract(row_data, r':({.+?})')]) min_max

with same output
